# Unity 3D stop physics on GameOver

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My game has a score. It also has multiple game objects which, on collision, += 10 to int score. The score script is attached to all of these game objects.

The game objects have a force applied to them at random time intervals. This force moves them right and then they stop. The player has a timeframe in which they can click on the object. If the player clicks in time, the object is propelled left and is stopped by a collision event which adds +10 to the score. If that timeframe expires, the game object has a force applied in the left direction anyways, but this causes the instantiation of the game over text.

Suppose the timeframe to click expires before the player can click. The game object is propelled left, and since the timer, and not the players click, caused this propulsion, GameOver happens which is just a GameOver text being instantiated.

**Here is the problem.**Since the score script is attached to all of these game objects, suppose object 1 times out and causes game over, objects 2 through 10 are on the same timer as object 1 and will still be pushed left on timeout. Also, the player can still click them and keep playing after game over.

My question is, how can I stop these game objects from moving on game over?

I can't disable colliders or destroy rigid body. Making thrust = 0 on GameOver kind of works, but only after the other 9 game objects time out and get kicked one more time. I can't make int score = 0 because I want the final score displayed. I can't destroy the score for the same reason. De queuing does nothing it just starts the timers over again.

I just need the score to stop incrementing on GameOver. If I could also stop the physics on the other 9 game objects that would be good too.

I hope I have provided enough information to get feedback.

Thanks

Comment: perhaps you can post the "score script" which causes you the problem, since you don't want to increase the score when `GameOver` occurs.

Comment: Ok I will post it when I get home

Comment: Great, it is rather hard to imagine what you encounter there, much harder to propose any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop physics by setting timescale to 0:

> When timeScale is set to zero the game is basically paused if all your functions are frame rate independent
>
> FixedUpdate functions will not be called when timeScale is set to zero

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html

Other options:
- Can set physic object rigidbodies to [x] kinematic, so they would stop
- Have bool gameover-varible and set it to true after timeout, then inside score scripts, if gameover variable is true, dont add new score anymore
- Disable scoring scripts when time is over
- Have global ScoreManager script, which adds/calculates the score, instead of multiple separate scoring scripts, easier to handle when to stop/enable it

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly this should stop all physics on the objects you want on all axis :

```
gameobject.find("object").getcomponent<Rigidbody2D>().constraints  = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeAll;
```

or

```
GameObjects[] ObjectsToFreeze = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("object")

foreach(gameobject obj in objectsToFreeze)

{

obj.getcomponent<Rigidbody2D>().constraints  = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeAll;

}
```